# How to get a Date object from a 12 hour time string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, timepicker

I am trying to provide a default value for a TimePicker object. But the that value I have is a string e.g `"12:00 PM"` And the picker needs a Date object.

I tried parsing the time directly into a Date object like shown below, but it does not work

```
let startTime = new Date("12:00 PM");
```

How can i convert this time string into a Date object so that i can provide the default value to the TimePicker.

Answer (score 1):

Ive been able to create a function that can do the conversion, since I did not find any solution to this.

```
const dateFromTime = ({ timeString }) => {
    const dateTime = new Date();
    let timeHours = parseInt(timeString.substring(0, 2));
    let timeMinutes = parseInt(timeString.substring(3, 5));
    let timeAMPM = timeString.substring(6,
    if (timeAMPM === "PM") {
        timeHours += 12;

    dateTime.setHours( timeHours, timeMinutes, 0, 0);
    return dateTime;
}
const dateTime = dateFromTime({ timeString: "12:00 PM" });
```

This get the current date and time and instead sets the time to the specified time. and returns that

For any improvements, please suggest the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input id="appt-time" type="time" name="appt-time" value="13:30">
```

JS

```
const timeFrom12hto24h = time12h => {
  const [time, meridiem] = time12h.split(" ");
  let [hours, minutes] = time.split(":");
  if (hours === "12") hours = "00";
  if (meridiem === "PM") hours = parseInt(hours, 10) + 12;
  return {hours, minutes}
};

const getMyObjectTime= timeFrom12hto24h('12:00 PM');

// apply the time to the HTML element
document.getElementById("appt-time").value = getMyObjectTime.hours + ':' + getMyObjectTime.minutes;

// one way to generate the needed time object
const dateInMiliseconds = new Date().setHours(getMyObjectTime.hours, getMyObjectTime.minutes, 0)
console.log(dateInMiliseconds);
```

In case there is moment.js already used in the project it would be like this:

HTML:

```
<input id="appt-time" type="time" name="appt-time" value="13:30">
```

JS:

```
// apply the time to the HTML element
document.getElementById("appt-time").value = moment("01:00 PM", 'hh:mm A').format('HH:mm')

// one way to generate the needed time object
let [hour, minutes] =  moment("01:00 PM", 'hh:mm A').format('HH,mm').split(',');
const dateInMiliseconds = new Date().setHours(hour,minutes, 0)
console.log(dateInMiliseconds);
```

Comment: Okay thank you for your answer. However, I find it a little verbose in the scope of React.js but it seems to get it right. So i will upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give the correct format to the Date object.

## solution 1

If you don't care about date then you can simply convert like this.

```
let startTime = new Date(`2022/01/01 12:00 PM`);
```

## solution 2

If you need today's date then you can simply convert like this.

```
let startTime = new Date(`${new Date().toDateString()} 12:00 PM`)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used date-and-time package to format current time. It's worked for me.

`npm install date-and-time`

Controller

```
const date = require("date-and-time");

const now = new Date();
const startTime = date.format(now, "HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Sorry Dilshan, but i'm trying to create a Date object using a time string not to format a Date object and get time from it.

Comment: You can try out my solution and see if it works for you in my use case. And if it helps you can please go ahead to upvote it, to help others and my self.